# WidgetKit - How to use real-time queries to update widget?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, widgetkit

In my app, I use `Firebase`'s `Firestore` for live data, so when a new post is created, the user receives it instantly.

Is there a way to duplicate that behavior in a widget extension? I tried the code below, but it only works when I run the project with the widget extension target selected.

```
import SwiftUI
import WidgetKit
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseAuth 

@main 
struct PostWidgets: WidgetBundle { 
    private let dependencyInjector = DependencyInjector.shared
 
    init() { 
        FirebaseApp.configure() 
        try! Auth.auth().useUserAccessGroup("\(Keys.appleTeamId)")
        dependencyInjector.register(target: PostWidgetsRepository.self, dependency: PostWidgetsFirestoreService())
 
        @Injected var postsService: PostWidgetsRepository
 
        postsService.subscribeToNewPosts { post in 
            if let post { 
                WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines() 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    var body: some Widget { 
        FriendsWidget() 
        SchoolWidget() 
    } 
}
```